# Should this container be a struct or a class?

Tags: c#, classes, serialization

I have a class that serves purely as a data container for passing values from a parsing class to a class responsible for saving the data. I have been wondering whether it would be more appropriate as a struct. The class definition is below.

```
internal class DataContainer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Sensor1Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<double?, int>> Sensor1Readings { get; set; }

    public string Sensor2Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<double?, int>> Sensor2Readings { get; set; }
}
```

The parser uses an iterator block to turn a large csv file into approximately 6000 `DataContainer`s. As they are created, each `DataContainer` is passed to the SaveContainer. The SaveContainer immediately reads the values and discards each object. Finally, the SaveContainer saves all the values to the database:

```
internal class FileParser
{
    // Much yak shaving...

    private IEnumerable<DataContainer> GetFileData()
    {
        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(this.FilePath))
        {
            string tableData = null;
            while ((tableData = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var sensor1Data = readFile.ReadLine();
                var sensor2Data = readFile.ReadLine();

                DataContainer currentData = this.CreateDataContainer(tableData, sensor1Data, sensor2Data);
                yield return currentData;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CollectData()
    {
        SaveContainer saveContainer = new SaveContainer();
        foreach (var data in this.GetFileData())
        {
            saveContainer.AddData(data);
        }

        saveContainer.Save();
    }
}
```

I have read Microsoft's [Choosing Between Class and Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) guidelines and I think that I mostly understand them (enough to say that this type does not meet the qualifications). I've also read some related Stack Overflow answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c). They seem to offer a wide variety of opinions on the matter.

I have no specific need to change the type definition, but its use is so particular and basic that a class seems unnecessarily complex. Would changing this class to a struct offer any compelling advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: my guts tell me that it should be a class, but I'm not sure why, also it depends on how often you are creating this DatacCntainers, is this a user action or you are batch parsing a lot of csv files?

Comment: Voted to close because this is example code. (Foo and Bar don't show up in production code, and if they do, this question is the least of your worries.)

Comment: The property and class names have been changed for proprietary reasons, but beyond that this is _exactly_ the code that I am using. Since when was genericizing variable names an issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close, but for a different reason. I feel like there isn't any code to review here. This type of theory question would likely be better received at [programmers.se].

Comment: @probackpacker AFAIK, it has always been an issue on CR. CR is about reviewing all aspects of a piece of code, including naming.

Comment: I humbly disagree with the assertion that this question is "off-topic". The question  contains *real* code and I am looking for specific feedback on "Best practices and design pattern usage" and "Performance".  Specifically, _is a struct or a class more appropriate for this use case?_ It is neither hypothetical nor theoretical but asks a legitimate design question about a segment of concrete, working code. I understand that this may not be an extremely typical CR question, in that it solely involves a simple class definition, but all I'm asking for is a chance to get some feedback.

Comment: @svick, I think your point is valid, but I don't think that generic variable names should necessarily mark a question as "off-topic". Is there specific value that the property names would add in regard to the question being asked? I changed them to be conservative (they're not _that_ sensitive) but I honestly think that they would detract more than they would contribute. That said, if it is _truly_ important, I will consider changing the names to reflect the original or at least something less generic.

Comment: There is still insufficient context for a review. (It could still be closed as "Unclear what you are asking".) What do you intend to do with this struct or class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Keep it a class

The linked MSDN guideline says so itself:

> **X AVOID** defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - it has an instance size under 16 bytes

It should be pretty clear that `DataContainer` is going to be **much** larger than 16 bytes.

One of the reasons this is a concern is that structs are stored on the stack.  The default .NET thread stack size is [1MB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4(v=vs.110).aspx), so in an extreme case, a struct which is too large could get you a StackOverflowException without any recursion required.